# javascript settimeout evaluate variables now versus later

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
function myFunction() {
var now = 3;
var later = 3;
setTimeout(function(){ alert(now * later); }, 1000);
now++;
later++;
}
```

The above code will alert the value "16", because both variables will be 4 when it executes.
Is there a way to get the value "now" to evaluate right now at its current value so that the final result is 12?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might pass `now` into the function as an argument, at the time the `setTimeout` is called:

```js
var now = 3;
var later = 3;
setTimeout(function(now) {
  alert(now * later);
}, 1000, now);
now++;
later++;
```

Or declare another variable that's assigned to the value of `now` at the time of the `setTimeout` call:

```js
var now = 3;
var later = 3;
const nowAtTimeoutCall = now;
setTimeout(function() {
  alert(nowAtTimeoutCall * later);
}, 1000);
now++;
later++;
```

Comment: Thanks, in the second solution, would the nowAtTimeoutCall remain constant even if the code is executed several times with different "now" values before the first one triggers?

Comment: Yes, every time the block runs, it'll create new variables, with a new `nowAtTimeoutCall` for each.